# bash function pass space & line separated arguments from sed

Tags: bash, macos, function, for-loop, sed

How do I pass arguments to function or loop in bash in my case?. The field separator would be space and as well as next line(\n). The goal is to get all the route commands from the log file and then re-apply the same but deleting them before applying.

file.log

```
Mon Nov  7 10:55:28 2016 bla bla bla
Mon Nov  7 10:55:28 2016 bla blabla bla
Mon Nov  7 11:19:27 2016 /sbin/route add -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
Mon Nov  7 11:19:27 bla bla bla
Mon Nov  7 11:19:27 2016 /sbin/route add -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
Mon Nov  7 11:19:32 2016 /sbin/route add -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
Mon Nov  7 11:19:32 bla blabla bla
Mon Nov  7 11:19:32 2016 /sbin/route add -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
Mon Nov  7 11:20:21 bla blabla bla
Mon Nov  7 11:20:21 bla bla bla
Mon Nov  7 11:20:23 bla bla bla
```

The following extracts the route commands from the log file to be added,

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' /path/to/file.log | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Here is what I'm trying with the bash function,

```
#!/bin/bash

add_routes() {

$1 delete $3 $4 $5 $6      #expecting: eg: /sbin/route delete -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
$@                         #expecting: eg: /sbin/route add -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255


}

add_routes $(sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' /path/to/file.log | awk '!seen[$0]++')
```

Desired output command to be executed in sequence from the above function(delete first to apply latest route network extracted from log),

```
/sbin/route delete -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route add -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route delete -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
```

from the above function, $@ executes pasting all the route commands in one line which fails. And the delete command(above $@ line) deletes only first route.

Anybody know how to get the desired output with functions or with `for loop` if it gets the job done?. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in BASH without `sed`:

```
while read -r; do
   read -ra arr <<< "/sbin/${REPLY#* /sbin/}" # strips anything before /sbin/
   [[ ${arr[0]} == /sbin/route ]] &&
   "${arr[@]/add/delete}" &&
   "${arr[@]}"
done < file.log
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a single awk command to do all:

```
awk '{sub(/^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){5}/, "")} $1 == "/sbin/route" && !seen[$0]++{
      s=$0; sub(/add/, "delete"); print; print s}' file.log | bash
```

Comment: Oops, in actual log file it don't start with the route command but prefixed with some date & time. It's my mistake for not exactly arranging file.log. BTW, i'm using sed to avoid duplicate routes as well. I really don't know we can do just with bash, good to know new things. Wondering if you can edit so that it reads route command even if it dosen't start first in a line...

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: NIce, the small issue with sort is i'm losing the sequence it has to be executed compared to awk

Comment: You can just replace my `grep|sort` command with your awk command. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: The output is null!

Comment: Yes, awk will not output anything. You can use `awk '{sub(/^(\S+\s+){5}/, "")} $1 == "/sbin/route" && !seen[$0]++{
     s=$0; sub(/add/, "delete"); $0 |& getline out; print out; s |& getline out; print out}' file.log` to get output as well.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I have edited awk command to work with non-gnu awk as well. Also I took out `getline`.

Comment: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {sub(/^(\S+\s+){5}/, "")} $1 == "/sbin/route" && !seen[$0]++{ s=$0; sub(/add/, "delete"); $0 >>>  |& <<<  getline out; print out; s |& getline out; print out}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

---  FYI, I'm on OSX

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove `getline` from `awk` command. I'm also on OSX and have tested it on OSX before editing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with passing your function the output of the sed command directly is, as you have seen, the output comes space separated ( i think ).

Sometimes you'll see people getting around this by playing games with IFS and OFS.  I always screw that up and think it looks messy.

I prefer doing this style of looping because it tends to work as I expect.  If you run a for loop over a file it can interpret spaces in the line as newlines and things get messy.  http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/loops/ Explains this and is worth a read.

The `while read x; do ... done < <(cmd)` style loop:

```
while read log_line;do

    add_routes ${log_line}

done < <(sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' file.log)
```

Basically you are redirection the output of `sed` to a fifo, then redirecting the fifo to the stdin of `read`.  `read` is smart enough to read in a single line of the output from sed into the `log_line` variable.

Now that `log_line` contains a single line of output you just pass that to your add_routes function as you had it written.

Sometimes it is necessary to do a `read -r`, if you don't want to interpret newlines, but obviously here you do!

For a full example...

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

add_routes(){
    echo "$1 delete $3 $4 $5 $6";
    echo $@;
}

while read thing;do

    add_routes ${thing}

done < <(sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' file.log)
```

file.log is as you laid it out.

output:

```
$ ./script.sh
/sbin/route delete -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route add -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route delete -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
```

Notice that I am echoing out the commands you wanted to run since i don't actually want to mess with my routes.

For more reading about bash redirection check out http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: Nice information!. I'm testing this, i'll get back and let you know. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: You worth bounty, right now it's not allowed me to do!

Comment: You might want to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and google bash fundamentals first. `read -r` has nothing to do with interpreting newlines btw.

Comment: Interesting read.  Mis interpreted the man page for reads -r, thanks for pointing it out.  I'll look to use xargs to avoid unnecessary looping in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk 'sub(".*/sbin/route add ","") {
    print "delete", $0
    print "add", $0
}' file |
xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 echo /sbin/route

$ ./tst.sh
/sbin/route delete -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route add -net 123.123.123.0 123.123.123.104 255.255.240.0
/sbin/route delete -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 111.111.111.111 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 4.4.2.2 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route delete -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 222.222.222.222 224.224.224.1 255.255.255.255
```

Just remove the `echo` when you're happy with the command line.

If you don't have GNU xargs then the `-d` argument may not be available and then you'd need to use this instead (untested):

```
awk -v ORS='\0' 'sub(".*/sbin/route add ","") {
    print "delete", $0
    print "add", $0
}' file |
xargs -0 -n 1 echo /sbin/route
```

Comment: `xargs: illegal option -- d
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]`

- FYI, I'm on OSX

Comment: `-d` must be a GNU-ism, sorry I didn't know that. Can you install GNU xargs? In any case, I just added a version that should work with any xargs by adding `-v ORS='\0'` at the start of the awk command and replacing `-d $'\n'` with `-0` in the xargs command.

Comment: No luck, probably I should consider installing gnu-xargs. I tried your updated section of awk, all the routes are pasted in one line and /sbin/route is only added to first delete and all the other are not followed by /sbin/route.

Comment: I will have to use this on multiple OSX nodes as a path and mostly avoiding extra installation and just trying with out of box solution as brew might not be found and again the extra work of brew installation and if already installed then the permission issues to be handeled!.

Comment: I meant patch instead path in above comment!

Comment: Yes they would all be on 1 line in the awk output because we're separating them by NUL chars in the awk output so they can be read as NUL-separated by xargs instead of newline-separated. Are you SURE you added the `-0` argument to xargs? I can't think of any reason why that would not work on any OS.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the multiline output of `sed` to `add_routes()` in a single pass when `add_routes()` is written to only handle one route.

The direct answer to your question, without rewriting your entire code, is to use `xargs` which can handle multiline and pass to `add_routes()` one line at a time (or 6 parameters).

All you need is to change this line:

```
add_routes $(sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' /path/to/file.log)
```

To this line:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(\/sbin\/route\ add \-net\)/\1/p' /path/to/file.log | xargs -n6 add_routes
```

`-n 6` tells `xargs` to pass `6` parameters at a time.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '\#^.*(/sbin/route add )#{s//\1/;h;G;s/add/delete/ep}' file
```

This filters the file using pattern matching, then duplicates the required input and replaces the first `add` by `delete`. The output is then evaluated.

This should also work with most sed's and shell's;

```
sed -n '\#^.*\(/sbin/route add \)#{s//\1/;h;G;s/add/delete/p}' file |
shell
```

Comment: `sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]` - Probably I should consider using gnu-sed in my OSX which you have already mentioned. I will have to use this on multiple OSX nodes and mostly avoiding extra installation and just trying with out of box solution as brew might not be found and again the extra work!. Let me consider this in other cases.